# append date and time before each line in a text log file in windows 10

Tags: windows, powershell, robocopy, iperf, xcopy

I want to append date and time before each line in a text log file in windows
I run iperf command in cmd in windows 10.
`iperf.exe -c192.168.5.199 -u -t4 -i1 -f Kbytes -w1024k -b1024k >> client-log.txt`

```
C:\iperf-2.0.9-win64\iperf-2.0.9-win64>iperf.exe -c192.168.5.199 -u -t4 -i1 -f Kbytes -w1024k -b1024k
------------------------------------------------------------
Client connecting to 192.168.5.199, UDP port 5001
Sending 1470 byte datagrams, IPG target: 11484.38 us (kalman adjust)
UDP buffer size: 1024 KByte
------------------------------------------------------------
[  3] local 192.168.5.133 port 50929 connected with 192.168.5.199 port 5001
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  3]  0.0- 1.0 sec   126 KBytes   126 KBytes/sec
[  3]  1.0- 2.0 sec   125 KBytes   125 KBytes/sec
[  3]  2.0- 3.0 sec   125 KBytes   125 KBytes/sec
......
......
......
......
......
......
```

**Expected output**

```
C:\iperf-2.0.9-win64\iperf-2.0.9-win64>iperf.exe -c192.168.5.199 -u -t4 -i1 -f Kbytes -w1024k -b1024k
------------------------------------------------------------
Client connecting to 192.168.5.199, UDP port 5001
Sending 1470 byte datagrams, IPG target: 11484.38 us (kalman adjust)
UDP buffer size: 1024 KByte
------------------------------------------------------------
Wed Jan 27 11:44:26 UTC 2021 [  3] local 192.168.5.133 port 50929 connected with 192.168.5.199 port 5001
Wed Jan 27 11:44:26 UTC 2021 [ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
Wed Jan 27 11:44:26 UTC 2021 [  3]  0.0- 1.0 sec   126 KBytes   126 KBytes/sec
Wed Jan 27 11:44:26 UTC 2021 [  3]  1.0- 2.0 sec   125 KBytes   125 KBytes/sec
Wed Jan 27 11:44:26 UTC 2021 [  3]  2.0- 3.0 sec   125 KBytes   125 KBytes/sec
```

---

**My efforts**

`C:\iperf-2.0.9-win64\iperf-2.0.9-win64>iperf.exe -c192.168.5.199 -u -t4 -i1 -f Kbytes -w1024k -b1024k | echo %DATE% %TIME% >> client-log.txt`

but its not adding date before each line it prints.

Comment: [1] iperf is not a PoSh command ... and you are piping its output to `echo` ... which is an alias for `Write-Output` ... and that does not accept pipeline input. ///// [2] the `%date%` stuff is for CMD.exe scripts ... it does not work that way in powershell.

Comment: how will it work then ?

Comment: i downloaded iperf3 and used this >>> `iperf3 -c iperf.scottlinux.com -u -t4 -i1 -f KBytes -b1024 -T "$(Get-Date -Format 'ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy')"` <<< and got lines like this >>> `Thu Jan 28 08:49:15 2021:  [  4]   0.00-1.00   sec  88.0 KBytes  87.9 KBytes/sec  11`. that bypasses most of powershell. if you need a different format, that would require a bit more PoSh code. [*grin*] ///// PS - i cannot use `-w1024K` ... it makes things hang for at least 8 minutes for me.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey  I am not getting append  date.                                                                 
#####  C:\iperf-2.0.9-win64>cd C:\iperf-2.0.9-win64   && iperf.exe -c 192.168.5.199 -i1 -t4 -b1024k -T "$(Get-Date -Format 'ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy')"

         `[  3]  0.0- 1.0 sec   128 KBytes  1.05 Mbits/sec`

Comment: are you running that in a powershell console? i ran mine in ps5.1 on win10, 20h2. also, i ran iperf3 ... you seem to be running iperf2. have you tried updating to the current version?

Comment: Thanks Lee,  finally It worked.  updaed iperf3 and powershel 5.1 in wondows 10

Comment: `cd C:\iperf-3.1.3-win32 && iperf3.exe -c 192.168.5.199 -i1 -t4 -b1024k -T "$(%DATE% %TIME%)"`

Comment: you are welcome! glad to have helped a bit. [*grin*]